# support libraries for greater than API 16?

Tags: android

i am developing an android application. My minsdk version is 16 so i was wondering that should i include

> com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1

or

> com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0

in my application. or when will i need these dependencies??

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Comment: Google keywords: `android support library`

Comment: It depends on you. If you are using appcompat then use the latest one com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0

Answer (score 2):

I think you need neither, because you minimum SDK level is 16, support libraries are for older versions. So every thing you need can be accessed from `android.app` name space, instead of support. If I may suggest something, moving to API 17 would give you a lot of benefits, especially with regards to fragments.

Comment: what kind of benefits, can u be more specific or some link would be perfect?

Comment: The biggest change is in child fragment manager, api level 17 has child fragment manager in android.app name space. So with api 16 if you want to nest fragments within, which is one of the biggest advantages of it, you have to use support library, but with api 17 you don't need support library and be 100% free of it. I have faced some bugs in support library fragments, that are still not fixed by google, and want to move to 17. Have a look here http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html